# Extensible/modular community building web software?

Tags: cms, forum

We are about to start a game website. We need some extensible web software, which could handle as many as possible of the following:

- Blog.
- Users & user profiles.
- Public forum with standard features like nesting, sticky/locked post, moderation tools, etc.
- Public events.
- User groups with private forum sections and events (for clan management).
- System of per-user "points" / inner currency / budget.
- Could run on Ruby on Rails or PHP with MySQL hosting.

If you are recommending a software, which can achieve the mentioned functionality using it's modules, please also mention names of the modules you would use.

Comment: (1) What do you mean with "Public events"? Just publishing a page/entry announcing an event? -- (2) How does the user point system work? Shall users earn points automatically when doing something on the site? Or do they get the points "manually" by admins?

Comment: 1) Exactly. 2) Earning point mechanics are related to the game, so very specific in this case. Just a budget with e.g. some API would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Drupal**](https://www.drupal.org/) (PHP/MySQL) is a possible solution.

#### Blog

Possible with Drupal’s core. Just create a content type called "Blog post".

For listing/pagination, you could use the basic "display on front page" feature, but I’d recommend to use the [**Views** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), which you’ll use for almost all sections of your site, anyway.

#### Users & user profiles

Possible with Drupal’s core. Each user comes with a profile.

#### Forum

You could use the basic node and comment system from Drupal core (each topic is a node, answers/posts are comments), but if you want a "standard" full feature forum, have a look at the [**Advanced Forum** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum).

#### Posting public events

Possible with Drupal’s core. Just create a content type called "Event" and add all necessary fields.

If you need more features, e.g., displaying your events in a calendar, have a look at the [**Event Calendar** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/event_calendar).

#### User groups

Each clan could be represented by a "group" from the [**Organic groups** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers communicate amongst themselves.

#### User points

The [**User points** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) is typically used for giving points for certain actions on the site (similar to Stack Exchange’s reputation), but it comes with an API:

> […] provides a callable interface, as well as a hook system for adding or subtracting points to a user account, as well as querying a user's account for how many points they currently have.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for me was using [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/), [bbPress](https://bbpress.org/) (forum), [BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/) (groups).

The per-user points and events parts are still missing, but I believe there will be other WordPress plugins to do that.